# How to prove that the two equations for the slope of the line of best fit are equivalent?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, estimation, linear, approximation

I was reading this great article on deriving the equation for the line of best fit (https://www.neelocean.com/simple-ols-estimators/), and got confused when I came across:

Rearranging:
$$\hat \beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i-n\bar x\bar y}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - n\bar x^2}$$

Or equivalently (and a bit more nealy):

$$\hat \beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2}$$

I understand that both these equations give the slope of the line of best fit but I fail to understand how they are equivalent. If someone can provide a step-by-step proof that these two equations are equivalent I will be extremely grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a FAQ, although it appears in many disguises.  The algebra is particularly simple once you realize it all comes down to the fact--which characterizes the means--that the sum of $x_i-\bar x$ and the sum of $y_i-\bar y$ are both zero.  It gets even easier once you have realized that the estimated slope does not change when you just shift the data points to the left and right or up and down.  This allows you to assume, *with no loss of generality,* that $\bar x = \bar y = 0.$  When that's the case the two formulas are obviously equal, *QED.*